# bash handle both starts with non-zero and zero value in if

Tags: bash

I need to compare two integer values and here is the if condition,

```
if [[ $VAL -ge 1000 ]] ; then
   #do something 
fi
```

But the problem is when it tries to compare with an integer value `010` got the error saying

`-bash: 01: value too great for base (error token is "01")`

I fixed this issue by using `$VAL#0` in if condition.

But still getting same kind of issue with it tries to compare integer value `0010` and it fixed with `10#${VAL}`.

The problem with proper integer values like `523` and getting below error,

`[[: #10523: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "#10523")`

Not sure how to make the if statement works with all the cases.

**Update (Solution):**

Found the fix.

```
VAL=$((10#$VAL))
```

Whatever value this will change it to decimal and reassign it to the same variable.

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think found the issue, am using multiple and condition on if statement like below,

`if [[ $VAL -ge 1000 && $VAR -le 2000 ]] ; then
 #do something 
fi`

In the above condition am doing both within same square brackets which was produced those issues. But when I split them as below it worked fine. 

`if [[ $VAL -ge 1000 ]] && [[ $VAR -le 2000 ]] ; then
 #do something 
fi`

Confused, what could be the difference between these two.

Comment: Me too faced the same issue but couldn't find it

Answer (score 0):

I think there's something not quite right with your example. 010 will not give a base error, but e.g. 090 will. That's because numbers with a leading zero are assumed to be octal.

To manually set the base, prefix the number with `10#`:

```
$ if [[ 100 -gt 090 ]]; then echo t; else echo f; fi
bash: [[: 090: value too great for base (error token is "090")
f

$ if [[ 100 -gt 10#090 ]]; then echo t; else echo f; fi
t
```

For your case, that means you should use:

```
if [[ "10#$VAL" -ge 1000 ]] ; then
   #do something 
fi
```